# Identify board game with a 1 ┤SK token

Tags: identify-this-game

Can someone please help identify the board game which has this token?[image]

Comment: It looks like what I have seen in several hidden role games where you have two different roles take actions based on them or bluff on what you claim to have but I can't remember the name.

Answer (score 23):

This is the [currency from Coup](https://boardgamegeek.com/image/1841941/coup).

Comment: That is the game that I could visualize but not name!